# Debug stand-alone JS in Aptana 3

Tags: javascript, aptana

I just want to run some example pieces of javascript which only output to the console... just for learning.  I can use Aptana OK for editing and I can wrap the js in some HTML and run it in a browser, but I cant figure out how to run it in aptana. I start the debug perspective but I can't see how to run the js file.  Can anybody help me understand how to do this?

Comment: Why not use a browser's developer tools?

Comment: That's what I'm doing @Joseph the Dreamer but I thought it would be convenient to do it in aptana.